# Update Access table with value from another table via INNER JOIN

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to update a column using pyodbc with data from a column in another table in the same database. I've tried:

```
cursor.execute('''
            UPDATE Prospect_SC_Fin_102016
            SET Prospect_SC_Fin_102016.Sym_Ky=Symbol_Ref_102016.Sym_Ky
            FROM Prospect_SC_Fin_102016
            INNER JOIN Symbol_Ref_102016
            ON Prospect_SC_Fin_102016.Symbol=Symbol_Ref_102016.Symbol;
            ''')
con.commit()
cursor.close()
con.close()
```

and get a "missing operator" syntax error.

I've also tried:

```
cursor.execute('''
            UPDATE Prospect_SC_Fin_102016
            SET Prospect_SC_Fin_102016.Sym_Ky=(SELECT Sym_Ky
            FROM Symbol_Ref_102016 WHERE Symbol IN
            (SELECT Symbol FROM Prospect_SC_Fin_102016));
            ''')
con.commit()
cursor.close()
con.close()
```

which also errors out. What's the correct logic here?

Comment: What database are you using? The first syntax looks like a function that recent PostgreSQL releases support, but I'm not sure other DBs do.

Comment: @FlipperPA it's an MS Access db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an Access database you would want to use a query of the following form:

```sql
UPDATE Prospect_SC_Fin_102016
INNER JOIN Symbol_Ref_102016
    ON Prospect_SC_Fin_102016.Symbol=Symbol_Ref_102016.Symbol
SET Prospect_SC_Fin_102016.Sym_Ky=Symbol_Ref_102016.Sym_Ky
```